# REST API Parameter precedence

Tags: api, http, rest

I'm working on creating a REST API. Lets say the resource I'm serving is called `object` and it contains a number of properties.

Apart from requesting the entire set of objects like this

`GET api.example.com/objects`

I want to allow requesting a single object by providing either the `objectid` or `objectname`,
like this

`GET api.example.com/objects?objectid=

GET api.example.com/objects?objectname=`

What I'm confused about is, how should I handle a request like this?

`GET api.example.com/objects?objectid=x&objectname=y`

In this case, should I return a `400 Bad Request`, or should one of the parameters take precedence over the other? How does REST define this behavior?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

REST generally assumes there is a unique URL for a resource, so it would be:

```
GET api.example.com/objects/objectId
```

Parameters are commonly used for searching, so you would have something like:

```
GET api.example.com/objects?objectName=x
```

Comment: In case of multiple search parameters, are they considered to be AND or OR?

Comment: I don't know what the REST recommendation is but I generally use AND for different parameters and OR for list arguments of a single parameters, so ?type=2,3&parent=10 would stand for ( parent = 10 AND ( type = 2 OR type = 3 )

Answer (score 1):

A better approach would be use a generic key in the parameter string to retrieve field values of your specific resource

```
GET api.example.com/objects/objectId?field=objectName,anotherField
```

It complements xpapad's suggestion, and can add scalable structure in how you define a consistent approach to your API design.